# Create an unsubscribe link for an EE mailing list outside of the email template

Tags: email, module

I am trying to create an unsubscribe link for the built in EE mailing list module that can be sent out without going through the Communicate page.

I know that within my email template, I can use the {unsubscribe_url} tag, but I need a way to allow users to unsubscribe when messages aren't sent through that template.

Is there any other way to generate an unsubscribe link, or can I set up a page with a form where users can enter their email address manually to unsubscribe?

Answer (score 1):

There are no tags to generate the unsubscribe link but if you know the email address that needs to be unsubscribed you can query the database to grab the "Authcode" which is needed to create the link.

This [**post on the EE Forum**](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/221774/#1034633) details how to accomplish this.